# How do I specify a JAR in a POM such that it is excluded from packaging but available when running from within IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a project where several dependency versions need to be chosen at deployment time - i.e. specified in the classpath.

The provided scope prevents the dependency being packaged but the project fails when I try to run from within IntelliJ IDEA

e.g.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

produces

```
{stacktrace ...}
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
```

If I remove the scope the project runs fine but, of course, includes the jar.

Comment: Are you running tests?

Comment: @khmarbaise No, there are no tests

Comment: @khmarbaise But, when I copy main into a test case and run that, it works! :-/

Comment: If this dependency is only needed during test you should give it scope test...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mark a jar as `<provided>`, the classes need to be provided by the container that runs the surrounding war/ear.

When you run your project from within IntelliJ, it is probably deployed on some kind of container. Make sure this container provides you `<provided>` dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the libraries under File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Libraries allows the app to run again.

Comment: That is probably the wrong approach. Make sure that the container you test in has the appropriate libraries included. Your approach seems brittle because you declare the same dependencies in the pom and in IntelliJ, possibly breaking the project if you don't keep both worlds synchronized.

Comment: I agree it's not a great approach because I'm aware that the versions in the POM could change without being reflected in the project settings and have made a comment to that effect. I could take the dependencies out of the pom altogether but that would fail when the build is run on the build server and it leaves the dependencies unstated. Adding the jars to the classpath in the run configuration isn't any better than specifying them in the project settings. Perhaps I need a way for IntelliJ to scan the pom and update its run settings from the provided dependencies, or have an option for it.

Comment: In which container does your war run when you start it with IntelliJ?

Comment: It's not a web app, this is a console app, so no container.

Comment: So how do you package? With the assembly plugin? Or shade plugin? "Provided" is not really meant to be used without containers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153378/discussion-between-sarah-phillips-and-jf-meier).

Answer (score 0):

Final approach was to create two maven profiles, one for running locally and one for packaging. The local profile used `compile` scope while the package profile used `provided`.